# What contributes to 'Other' section in Native memory snapshot in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As I load more data into my application, 'Other' section keeps growing in my web app. What does this mean? I have checked my code for any memory leaks and couldn't find any. Also, the objects I hold in my application are very much needed for the application.

Varunkumar Nagarajan

[image: Native Memory Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

How do you checking your app for a leak?

Have you seen [Tool to track down JavaScript memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969062/tool-to-track-down-javascript-memory-leak/12061206#12061206)

Native memory snapshot is an experimental feature and couldn't be used for detecting memory leaks at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I followed the similar approach for memory leaks. I am not trying to use Native Memory Snapshot to detect memory leaks. Just trying to understand what that section is all about.