# Javascript memory and leak problems

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-leaks, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

My site is pretty standard ecom site, it isn't a JS backed standalone app or anything, it's just a site which uses JS for standard stuff, as well as some jquery plugins to do a few things.

I'm trying to do some JS memory evaluation on my site. I've done this by looking at the Chrome Task Manager and through Heap Snapshots.

Initailly my site on first load sits between 35MB (i.e 35,000K) and 40MB on the task manager. This is the largest of any tab, if I have several tabs of other websites open at the same time.
If I refesh the page it jumps up to 55-60, another refresh sees it jump to 65-70MB.

On a normal page in a workflow, it fluctuates between 45-65 (sometimes 75 depending on what you're doing). Clicking around and doing the workflow from page to page sees the memory jump up to 85-100, and increases as you continue through the site.

I've tried to do a few things like check for:

- detacted nodes
- heap snapshots & looking at the deltas
- amix's MemoryLeakChecker checking size of objects

I'd need a deeper dive to look for circular references or closure problems.

Heap snapshots don't reveal much, most of the top lists are (array), (string), (system). The snapshots sit between 4.8MB, 5.1MB, 5.8MB, 6.8MB and increase.

I've got a few questions as result:

- `How do I understand the different metrics between snapshot memory and task manager memory`
- `Are there any good tutorials (apart from the ones on the Google Developers site)?`
- `How much memory is considered acceptable? Given in the task manager my site is always the highest?`
- `Do I have a memory leak? Apart from the steps I've described above (which I haven't found anything concrete from) is there any other ways I can find leaks?`
- `Can you suggest any tools apart from the Chrome Dev Tools (a lot of the tools mentioned on Google for Firefox are not compatible with the latest version, eg: Leak Monitor for FF)`

As a side note, most of my functions are low key operations, and don't exceed 200ms (based on a CPU profile). What is a good benchmark I should be aiming for? Is 200ms high?

Comment: When you say "refresh" you mean "F5", right?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What you are describing is not a memory leak, it's a garbage that Chrome knows of and that will be removed whenever Chrome decides it's time to do it. To explain this, lets have a closer look at the scenario you have described.

### Making memory to 'leak'

- First lets open up a new incognito window (just to be sure that browser extensions are not affecting our results) and navigate to google.com.
- Then, lets open the Task Manager and enable "JavaScript Memory" column (by right-clicking on the Task Manager window). We need this column to be sure that the memory we will be 'leaking' is being, in fact, allocated by JavaScript. We end up with something like this:

[image: First load]

- Now, as you suggested, we should reload the page couple of times and observe the memory of our tab going up:

[image: After 5+ reloads]

So far, so good - everything works exactly as you described it.

### Wait a second...

However, lave your cursor inactive for half a minute, or go to another tab and you will observe a huge memory usage drop on our 'Tab:google'. Why is that? What happened there? Who cleaned up our 'leaked' memory for us?

### The Memory Usage Drop

To investigate that, lets repeat what we have done so far, so that 'Tab:google' uses a lot of memory again. Then, lets open Chrome Developer Tools and start recording on the 'Timeline' tab. After that, lets change a tab for couple of seconds and when memory drops stop 'recording' on the 'Timeline'. You should end up with this:

[image]

In the last couple of seconds of our recording mysterious 'GC Events' appeared. Exactly in the same time when the memory was released. Coincidence? Nope.

### GC Events

GC stands for the [Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). It's a mechanism that "attempts to reclaim garbage, or memory occupied by objects that are no longer in use by the program". So it turns out that memory of our tab was polluted by garbage and GC was capable of getting rid of these garbage for the whole time (you can even force garbage collection using button at the bottom of the 'Timeline' tab). So why it decided not to? Why it waited for us to stop interacting with the page or change the tab?

### Lazy Garbage Collector

The short answer is that garbage collection has to 'freeze' the execution of all scripts before any work can be done. Also, it can take significant amount of CPU time to execute. This can result in lag, choppy animations, unresponsive controls etc. That's why Chrome waits for the *right moment* to call the garbage collection. And the best moment to do it is when user is not looking.

In addition, please note that 'GC Events' come in series, there are always couple of them with short breaks in between. These breaks are meant for 'normal' JavaScript to execute making the garbage collection less noticeable.

### Live Objects

Take a look at "JavaScript Memory" tab at the top two screenshots in this post again. You will notice that this column contains two numbers. First one is memory "reserved for JavaScript VM
heap", the other one is "how much memory live (reachable) objects
comprise" ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/aTMVGoNM0VY/bLmf3l2CpJ8J)). When benchmarking your applications you should worry only about the second value, all the rest will be handled by GC.

### An example of a leak

A real JavaScript leak can happen ie. in a web chat application. If, over time, it will use more and more 'live' memory while always displaying only last 10 messages **then** we can talk about a leak. Such leak, will eventually crash a tab (or a browser).

### Conclusion

For scripts running on the page, reloading the page (or going to another location) is equal to restarting your computer while your ANSI C app is running. After that, you should think about all the memory allocated by your scripts as wiped out. The only reason why, in practice, this may not happen immediately after reloading the page is that browser is waiting for the right moment to clean up. And you, as a web developer, should not be concerned about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still think that your page are leaking you can use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969062/tool-to-track-down-javascript-memory-leak/12061206) to track down the leaked objects.