# Chrome timeline tool unreliable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I got this backbone app I am trying to debug,

I let the timeline recording, the app is using more and more memory, but If i go into profile, and take a heap snapshot, I always get the same number (6mb) like if my app is not leaking.

Plus when I take that snapshot the timeline is effectively getting back to 6mb. I'm not sure what to do of this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is perfectly fine and your app is probably not leaking any memory. What you are confused about is a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (GC).

GC is a mechanism that "attempts to reclaim garbage, or memory occupied by objects that are no longer in use by the program". It's quite normal to see memory going up and up on the timeline and it doesn't necessarily mean that application is leaking memory. It means that garbage is being accumulated in the memory but your browser (and more precisely - JavaScript engine) knows about it and will remove it whenever Chrome decides it's time to do it (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167013/javascript-memory-and-leak-problems/14188539#14188539)). Try clicking on the 'collect garbage' button ([image: "Collect Garbage" Chrome DevTools button]), it forces garbage collection and you will notice immediate drop on the timeline.

Getting back to making snapshots and the reason why you always end up with 6MB. First thing that happens when heap snapshot is created is... garbage collection. It's because DevTools don't want to obscure the snapshot with stuff that is no longer in use and should be removed.

I strongly recommend reading [official docs about heap profiling](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling).

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'm a bit upset at the garbage collector it let build up memory a lot (for a mobile app between 6 & 18mb is alot)

Comment: @CedricDugas You need to understand that garbage collection takes quite a lot of time and suspends all JavaScript execution. Therefore, Chrome faces a hard task of running GC as much as needed but also trying to avoid situations where GC makes app unresponsive (that's why GC is being called, among others, when app is not being used eg. when you change the tab or minify the browser). Anyway, you can still improve your app by not allocating new memory so often (eg. by reusing objects). This will reduce memory use growth and, as a result, need for frequent GC calls.