# Understanding Node count using Timeline Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a web application, in which a div is created on every `mousemove` event.

When profiling using Chrome Developer Tool Timeline, I see an increase of Node Counts (green line), but a really small number of `Detached DOM tree` when moving the mouse.
When the mouse is not being moved, the Node Counts are steady an never decrease/increase.

I would like to know:

- How exactly Node count (green line) works? Does provide memory information cumulatively respect the start of the recording?
- I was suspected a DOM memory leak, but taking a HEAP I see few `Detached DOM tree`. What could be issue for a steady increase of Node count?
- Does Node count effect the total memory of the JS application?
- What is the difference between `Document DOM tree / xxx entries` and `Object Count`?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

After some research, I suspect that Node Counts going up does not necessary represents a leak of memory in this case (also Running Chrome/Task Manager I see the JS Memory stable and not continuously increasing).
It most probably represents an in memory usage by the browser, when in fact I do not move the mouse for 30 seconds or open another tab/window, the Garbage Collector kick in and memory is being cleared as in the next image.
By the way any expert advice on this is very very welcome :)

[image]

Interesting:

[Javascript memory and leak problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167013/javascript-memory-and-leak-problems/14188539#14188539)

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis