# Understanding 'Native Memory profiling' in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am building an application with a simple search panel with few search attributes and a result panel. In the result panel, I am rendering the data in a tabular form using [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).

After few searches (AJAX call to server), the page gets so much loaded and it eventually crashes after sometime. I have checked the DOM count and the JavaScript heap usage for possible memory leaks. I couldn't find anything wrong there. However, when I ran the experimental native memory profiler, I see that the "JavaScript external resource" section uses 600+ MB memory. On running the garbage collector, it is getting down to few MBs. I have couple of questions here:

1. What contributes to the "JavaScript external resource" section? I thought it corresponds to the JSON data / JavaScript sources which gets transferred from the server. FYI, the gzipped JSON response from the server is ~1MB.
2. Why is Chrome not releasing the memory pro-actively instead of crashing the page? Again, when I manually run the garbage collector, it is releasing the memory used by "JavaScript external resources".

How do I fix the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

JS Heap Profiler makes a snapshot of the objects in the javascript but javascript code may use native memory with help of "Int8Array", "Uint8Array", "Uint8ClampedArray", "Int16Array", "Uint16Array", "Int32Array", "Uint32Array", "Float32Array" and "Float64Array".
So when you take a snapshot it will have only small wrappers that point to native memory blocks.
Unfortunately heap snapshot does not provide data about the native memory that was used for these kind of objects.
Native heap snapshot is able to count that memory and now we know that the page uses native memory via an array or via an external string.

I'd like to know how did you check that the page has no memory leaks? Did you use three snapshot technique or just checked particular objects?
[Tool to track down JavaScript memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969062/tool-to-track-down-javascript-memory-leak/12061206)

Comment: I used the three snapshot approach and I couldn't find anything wrong there. What does "JS external resource" section mean?