# Memory is bloated but freed after closing chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I'm fighting a leak on a page, which makes large AJAX requests and replaces page content once in several seconds.

If I open the page in Chrome Dev Tools, I see that memory usage grows over time (from one memory snapshot to another). There are no explicit leaks on the page ([the three-snapshot technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19621074/finding-javascript-memory-leaks-with-chrome) shows there are none)

[image: Memory is accumulated under "Global handles"]

According to Google Dev tools, the memory accumulated under GC Roots -> "Global handles", in some map. As I said, closing Chrome Dev Tools result in disappearing of this memory (i.e. memory usage drops from 600+Mb to 40Mb for the page). At the same time, pressing "GC" does not help, the memory remains in place.

But if the page is remained open for several hours, it may eat gigabytes and become unresponsive.

Google Chrome version is Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) on MacOS 10.12.6.

Any hint on how to fix/avoid such memory bloat is appreciated.

Comment: devtools retains the objects shown in its console/watches/elsewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm I stopped recording on Network panels (and logging of XHR requests), the memory still goes up. Really strange.

Comment: I have the same problem. I was debugging what I thought was a huge memory leak in my Chrome App but after quite some time I realized that the dev console itself was the memory leak. Try to open the console for a tab that shows a video. Each and every video fragment loaded by XHR will stay in memory and after some time Chrome will use gigabytes of memory. And it doesn't help if you switch off network recording. As I see, it's a bug in Chrome.